# retrieve corresponding TH value when TR is clicked using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to get the TH value of the corresponding TD index when the TR is clicked. So in the following table:

```
<table>
 <thead>
  <th>dogs</th>
  <th>cats</th>
  <th>lizards</th>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>3</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

with the following js:

```
$("tr").live("click", function() {
    //get values of row headers
    alert( $(this).closest('table').find('th').eq($(this).index()).val() );
 });
```

when you click on cell 1 would alert "dogs", clicking on cell 2 would alert "cats", etc.

Currently my code just alerts a blank alert box (nothing) but kicks up no errors either.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want `.val()`. You want `.text()` instead.

**EDIT:** As per the comments, since you still want it to work by binding to the `<tr>`, the final code should look like the following:

```
$("tr").live("click", function(event) {
    //get values of row headers
    alert($(this).closest('table').find('th').eq($(event.target).index()).text());
});
```

Note the passing in of the `event` object to the handler, and then using [`event.target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) to reference the element that was actually clicked.

Demonstrated [here](http://jsfiddle.net/greglockwood/EcDHe/1/).

Comment: thanks Greg, that works but I've got a new problem now: it appears the index() value is wrong because in my table when I click on "2" for example if alerts "dogs" and 3 alerts "cats". Any idea why that could be?

Comment: Yep - you want to target the `<td>`, not the `<tr>` with your main selector. :-)

Comment: need to use the <tr> click unfortunately because it is easier with some other stuff I am doing with the entire row... thoughts?

Comment: Sure - just have the click function take in the eventObj parameter, and then get the index of the actual element clicked (the `<td>`) by using `event.target` instead of `this`. See http://jsfiddle.net/greglockwood/EcDHe/1/ for an example.

Comment: Again, you were faster with building a fiddle and writing an answer :)

Comment: @Simon Maybe this time, but I'm not always the fastest. At least themerlinproject can be confident of the answer if 2 people suggested it!

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems with your code. As GregL already posted, you have to replace val() with text(). You're also getting the index of the tr and use it so select the th. So get the index of the td instead and it works:
http://jsfiddle.net/gF9A4/

Comment: thanks Simon, I need it to be on TR click because it is a lot easier with some other stuff I'm doing with the row. any idea how I could still get it to work using TR click?

Comment: You can check the index of the element that is actually clicked (the td) instead of the index of the element that the event-handler is attached to (the tr) by replacing this with event.target. See http://jsfiddle.net/EBJ8C/ for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the cell in question might have elements inside it, expecting the event target to be a cell doesn't seem reliable. So the first step should be to test if it's a cell and if not, go up the DOM to the first TD (or possibly TH) and get its index.

Then get the containing table and get the text content of the cell in the first row with the same index. Putting a listener on every row doesn't seem sensible, if the listener is put on the table, then the code is very much simpler and only one listener is required.

A plain javascript solution uses a little more code, but it's quite reliable:

```
function getHeadingText(e) {
  var tgt = e.target || e.srcElement;
  var cell;

  // Make sure the tgt is a table cell
  while (tgt && (!tgt.tagName || tgt.tagName.toLowerCase() != 'td')) {
    tgt = tgt.parentNode;
  }
  cell = this.rows[0].cells[tgt.cellIndex];

  // For debug
  alert(cell.textContent || cell.innerText);

  return cell.textContent || cell.innerText;

}
```

It can be attached using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){$('table').click(getHeadingText);});
```